# Trigger that validates criteria, IF no, then keep the original Id

Tags: trigger, account, event

I have a trigger here I wrote to validate criteria based on the Event & Account object. The 2nd IF statement is what I'm having issues with.  What I need is:  If any of this criteria isn't met, then just leave the OwnerId (Assigned To [Event Object] stay what it was, or in this case is.  Could someone please assist?  It's highlighted below.  Thanks!

```
trigger updateOwner on Event (before insert) {
    for(Event evt:Trigger.new){
        Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Event.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
        if(rt_map.get(evt.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Procedure Scheduler')){
            Account acc = [select Id, Primary_FCE__c, Primary_Rep__c, USD_AF_Region__c from Account WHERE Id=:evt.WhatId];
            evt.OwnerId = acc.Primary_FCE__c;
            // THE FOLLOWING CODE IS IN QUESTION
            if(rt_map.get(evt.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Procedure Scheduler') && acc.USD_AF_Region__c == NULL){
                evt.OwnerId = evt.OwnerId;
            // END QUESTION AREA
                if(rt_map.get(evt.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Procedure Scheduler') && acc.Primary_FCE__c == NULL && acc.Primary_Rep__c == NULL){
                    Regional_Admins__c ra = [select Id, Name, Primary_FCE_REP__c from Regional_Admins__c WHERE Name =: acc.USD_AF_Region__c]; 
                    evt.OwnerId = ra.Primary_FCE_REP__c;
                }    
            }
        }                                                      
    }
}
```

Error I receive when trying to save the event record:

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger updateOwner caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: updateOwner: execution of BeforeInsert caused by:
>   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject:
>   Trigger.updateOwner: line 15, column 1

Comment: You are fetching Accounts by using `evt.whatId` for Events of recordType `Procedure Scheduler` - do you know for sure that these Events are always children of Account?  And if they are, you have the `evt.account` relationship that you can exploit instead of whatId

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a trigger for validation, I recommend you take the same approach as validation rules do which is to test for the "failure" or opposite condition of what you want to be true.

What's happening here is that you're trying to assign a value to itself which is something that apex isn't going to allow you to do. You only want to make changes when that condition isn't being met. Your test needs to be

```
if(!(rt_map.get(evt.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Procedure Scheduler') && acc.USD_AF_Region__c == NULL)){
```

If the above returns true, then you don't need to do anything and can exit your trigger. If it's false, then you can test your other conditions to determine what corrective actions you need to take in your trigger logic on the id's that don't pass the criteria. Those that do, just remove them from your list of Ids that your testing and add those that don't to another or something along those lines.